# PHP file_get_contents then replace string in a function

Tags: php, function, file-get-contents, phpmailer, str-replace

> ```
> **User_Tpl.html**
> <html><head></head>
> <body>
> Hello {NAME},
> Business name : {BUSINESS_NAME}.
> Tel : {TELEPHONE}.
> Mob : {MOBILE}.
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

```
function mailFooter($content) {

  $sBusiness = 'Business name';
  $sTelp = '0';
  $sMobile = '0';

  $content = str_replace('{BUSINESS_NAME}', $sBusiness, $content);
  $content = str_replace('{TELEPHONE}', $sTelp, $content);
  $content = str_replace('{MOBILE}', $sMobile, $content);

  return $content;
}

$content = file_get_contents('page/email/User_Tpl.html');
$content = str_replace('{SUBJECT}', $subject, $content);
$content = str_replace('{NAME}', $ownerName, $content);

**mailerFooter($content);**
// always return {BUSINESS_NAME}, {TELEPHONE}

$mail->AddAddress( $email );
$mail->SetFrom($name );
$mail->AddReplyTo( $reply );
$mail->Subject = trim($subject);
$mail->MsgHTML( trim($content) );
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Send();
```

im using PHPMailer as Mailer library and how to replace those {strings} inside the mailFooter() function.

Comment: Doesn't make sense; check [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qmICKH)

Comment: `mailerFooter($content);` function is called `mailFooter()`

Comment: @Bondye I hope that's just a typo.

Comment: So you are writing your own templating engine? You should try twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use array

```
$content ='
<html><head></head>
<body>
Hello {NAME},
Business name : {BUSINESS_NAME}.
Tel : {TELEPHONE}.
Mob : {MOBILE}.
</body>
</html>';

$search= array ('{BUSINESS_NAME}','{TELEPHONE}','{MOBILE}');
$replace=array($sBusiness,$sTelp,$sMobile);
$content =str_replace($search,$replace,$content);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private arr = array(
    "{title}" => "Home page",
    "{email}" => "my@mail.com",
    ...
    );
    private $content = "Title for my site - {title}, if you interesting my email addres -> {email}"

$this->content = strtr($this->content, $this->arr);

echo $this->content;
```

This return -> "Title for my site - Home page, if you interesting my email addres -> my@mail.com"